# elasticsearch query string probplem with lowercase and underscore

Tags: elasticsearch

I create a custom analyzer in my Elasticsearch, I want to seperate from only white space of my words in my defined field, is "my_field". And my search needs to be case insensitive, for this feature, I used lowercase filter.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
           "type":      "custom",
           "tokenizer": "whitespace",
           "filter": [
               "lowercase",
               "trim"
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "mappings" : {
     "my_type" : {
          "properties" : {
               "my_field" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "analyzer" : "my_custom_analyzer"
                }
           }
     }
 }
```

After that this creation, I analyze my sample data:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
   "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
   "text": "my_Sample_TEXT"
}
```

and the output is

```
{
    "tokens": [
       {
          "token": "my_sample_text",
          "start_offset": 0,
          "end_offset": 14,
          "type": "word",
          "position": 0
       }
    ]
 }
```

I have many data in my documents and in "my_field" that contains "my_Sample_TEXT" but when I search for this text using query string, result returns 0:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "my_type",
            "query" : "*my_sample_text*",
            "analyzer" : "my_custom_analyzer",
            "enable_position_increments": true, 
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

My result is:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I found that, this problem happens when my text has underscore and uppercase text, can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Elasticsearch version?

Comment: Following answer is for ES 6.x

Comment: thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to change your mapping part of "my_filed" as below:

```
            "my_field" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "my_custom_analyzer"
                "search_analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
            }
```

Because, ES use standart analyzer when you do not set any analyzer. And standart analyzer can create multiple tokens from your underscored text.

Comment: i update my elastic search to 6.1 and apply your advice, my problem fixed

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is ok for you please, could you accept as accepted solution?